# Boost directory iterator "no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, directory, filesystems

I am using a boost::filesystem::directory_iterator to iterate over the contents of a folder(non-recursively) and count how many elements are in the folder.  I am able to iterate over the entire folder, but when the boost::filesystem::directory_iterator advances to the end iterator an error is thrown:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::filesystem::filesystem_error: boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: No such file or directory
```

I do not see how I am using the directory iterator incorrectly in this code, which is the code that throws the error:

```
boost::filesystem::path pcdFileDir(getPCDFilePath().string().substr(0, getPCDFilePath().string().find_last_of(boost::filesystem::path::preferred_separator)));
      std::cout << "pcdFileDirectory: " << pcdFileDir.string() << std::endl;
      size_t file_count = 0;
      for(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr(pcdFileDir); itr != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); ++itr){
        std::cout << itr->path() << std::endl;
        file_count++;
      }
      return file_count;
    }
```

pcdDir has the value ../out/autzen.  In ../out/autzen are 54 folders containing pcd files following the patter autzen_1, autzen_2, etc, and autzen.pcd.  The output of the print statement in the for loop is this:

```
"../out/autzen/autzen.pcd"
"../out/autzen/autzen_1"
"../out/autzen/autzen_10"
"../out/autzen/autzen_11"
"../out/autzen/autzen_12"
"../out/autzen/autzen_13"
"../out/autzen/autzen_14"
"../out/autzen/autzen_15"
"../out/autzen/autzen_16"
"../out/autzen/autzen_17"
"../out/autzen/autzen_18"
"../out/autzen/autzen_19"
"../out/autzen/autzen_2"
"../out/autzen/autzen_20"
"../out/autzen/autzen_21"
"../out/autzen/autzen_22"
"../out/autzen/autzen_23"
"../out/autzen/autzen_24"
"../out/autzen/autzen_25"
"../out/autzen/autzen_26"
"../out/autzen/autzen_27"
"../out/autzen/autzen_28"
"../out/autzen/autzen_29"
"../out/autzen/autzen_3"
"../out/autzen/autzen_30"
"../out/autzen/autzen_31"
"../out/autzen/autzen_32"
"../out/autzen/autzen_33"
"../out/autzen/autzen_34"
"../out/autzen/autzen_35"
"../out/autzen/autzen_36"
"../out/autzen/autzen_37"
"../out/autzen/autzen_38"
"../out/autzen/autzen_39"
"../out/autzen/autzen_4"
"../out/autzen/autzen_40"
"../out/autzen/autzen_41"
"../out/autzen/autzen_42"
"../out/autzen/autzen_43"
"../out/autzen/autzen_44"
"../out/autzen/autzen_45"
"../out/autzen/autzen_46"
"../out/autzen/autzen_47"
"../out/autzen/autzen_48"
"../out/autzen/autzen_49"
"../out/autzen/autzen_5"
"../out/autzen/autzen_50"
"../out/autzen/autzen_51"
"../out/autzen/autzen_52"
"../out/autzen/autzen_53"
"../out/autzen/autzen_54"
"../out/autzen/autzen_6"
"../out/autzen/autzen_7"
"../out/autzen/autzen_8"
"../out/autzen/autzen_9"
```

As you can see, it covers every element in the folder correctly.

Edit: Using a range-based for loop as suggested by @Chris_Stathis with the exact syntax:

```
  for(auto &file : boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(pcdFileDir)){
    std::cout << file.path() << std::endl;
    file_count++;
  }
```

does not resolve the error.

Comment: Please post a complete example (what is pcdFileDir?) Also, consider using range-based for loops for this: `for (auto &file : boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir))`

Comment: @ChrisStathis Using a range based for loop may be better design depending upon your viewpoint, but it does not resolve the error.  I will update the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, at first boost threw the same error as yours then it started to throw std::bad_alloc. I resolved it in two steps.

1. I built boost libraries with the same version of GCC that is used to compile my project. Since I have different versions of GCC on target machine (4.4.7 and 6.3.0), I guess there may be some issues caused by this.
2. I removed all cmake temporary folders and files and rebuilt my project from scratch. Try this if you use cmake. Don't forget to "make clean".

I suspect that the key to solve the problem was step 2.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was caused because I compiled with -`D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`

Removing it from the `CXXFLAGS` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here I propose two solutions that fixed my issue:

- Make sure that in your directory that you want to iterate, there is not any files/folders with Unicode characters in the name. If that is the case, you need to create your `boost::filesystem::path` object (e.g. `pcdFileDir` in your case) with a `wstring` constructor (instead of `std::string`).
- **(For Windows Only)** Make sure that the directory that you are iterating, does not have a folder/file that its path exceeds the maximum length of a path on Windows. (~256 characters).